# Hibernate Criteria Child Restriction

Tags: hibernate

I have a criteria to review list of parent objects

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class,"parent")

but i need to add a restriction on the list of the child objects , since 
I dont need all the child objects

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the specifics of the restriction you want to add, it will look like this substituting in your own restriction for `"yourRestriction"`.

In its current form, this will look for values in the `someColumn` column of the `parent` table for values that are equal to the String `"yourRestriction"`.

```
Criterion restriction = Restrictions.eq("parent.someColumn", "yourRestriction");
criteria.add(restriction);
```

More info:

- [Hibernate Criteria documentation for more examples](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objecstate-querying-criteria)
- [Restrictions documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) for my types of `Restrictions` like `gt` (greater than) and `ge` (greater than or equal to)

**EDIT: to create a restriction on a child collection:**

```
// Give the child collection an alias
criteria.createAlias("childCollectionNameInParentClass", "childCollectionAlias");

// Create the restriction on the child collection's column
Criterion restriction = Restrictions.eq("childCollectionAlias.someColumn", "someRestriction");
```

Comment: What i need is restriction on child collection i need to fetch only some child objects

Comment: I edited my answer to include how to create a restriction on a child collection

Comment: This code for restriction on child collection doesn't work, in the prepared Objects, child objects doesn't filter. All child records present in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way to do this :

```
criteria.setFetchMode("someColumn", FetchMode.EAGER);//It is deprecated but it works fine
Criteria criteriaChildField = criteria
                    .createCriteria("someColumn");

criteriaChildField.add(Restrictions.eq("restrictionAttribut", YOUR_RESTRICTION));
```

Hope this helps.